# How to get data from database to the Views in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I dont understand how to make the data work between the different pages. I have my database and the views but how do I make a DataTable fill to put in a HTML UL ou TABLE?

Comment: I highly recommend completing an MVC tutorial. There's a few available when you google "mvc tutorial" - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: The tutorial only shows the viewbag thing. The problem is that I have data on my SQL DataBase and I need to retrieve it. Where and how I get the data from it? In the controller or the model?

Comment: The controller populates the data in your model which you return to the view.  Perhaps you should look for an MVC4 tutorial with EntityFramework for SQL Server.  I found that an easy way to interact with a SQL database. Completing any MVC tutorial will help you understand the basics of views, models and controllers.

Answer (score 2):

That's where controllers and view models come in. Your controller should interact with a repository (or an abstraction of it) to obtain the data it needs, and instantiate and populate a view model. The view model is agnostic of where/how the data was obtained.

Your view then consumes the view model. Done properly, the view and view model will contain little or no logic, and certainly no direct data access logic.

I would strongly suggest downloading one or more [sample MVC projects](http://www.asp.net/mvc/samples) and stepping through the code.

Comment: Now it gets easy. I got the data with the controller. Than the model get its and send it to the view. But I thing that it has especifics funtcions and classes to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It would take to long to properly answer you question in this forum. You really need to do some research on MVC, I recommend starting with the tutorials at the [ASPNET MVC site](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and especially this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4)

Comment: The problem with the tutorial is the Razor thing. I´m using ASPX.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

I must create something of variable that can handle with collections ou sort of it. In my case i have created a datatable in the model

```
namespace sjnj.Models
{
    public class GameViewModel
    {
           [Display(Name = "Lista dos jogos")]
           public DataTable selectListajogo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then, in the controller, I make the normal database connection and feed it, returning the data when calling the view.

```
GameViewModel selectJogo = new sjnj.Models.GameViewModel();

//a lot of code here...

selectJogo.selectListajogo.Rows.Add(dtBuscajogo.Rows[i]["id"], dtBuscajogo.Rows[i]["nome"]);

//a lot of code here...

return View("Insert", (GameViewModel)selectJogo);
```

And then call Model.selectListaJogo in a loop on the view.